# use just the scope for fields_for with nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have 2 classes, A and B

```
class A
  has_many :bs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bs
end

class B
   belongs_to :a
end
```

B has a field called :group and I want to group my b's by group in the form.

fields_for does 2 things, it 1) adds a scope around nested form elements, and 2) it iterates through the attributes. I only want the first part, the nested scope.  Is there a way to just scope the nesting so I can manually group my nested objects?

In pseudo code what I want is

```
<%= form_for a do |f| %>
  <%= scope_for :gs do |g| %>
      <% f.object.bs.group_by{|x| x.group} do |k,v| %>
    <h3> Group <%= k %> </h3>
    <% v.each do |b| %>
       <%= g.text_field :field1
```

...

Is there a Rails form helper that achieves this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in helper that I know of that will let you do this, but it is possible to hack together a solution using just `fields_for`. The trick is to have a separate `fields_for` block for each group:

```
 <% f.object.bs.group_by(&:group).each do |k, v| %>
   <%= f.fields_for "b_groups[]" do |g| %>
     <!-- ... -->
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: i wound up doing something just like this but your answer effectively the same solution, thanks for the reply.